# Which do I choose: Web Role with Worker Threads, or Worker Role with HWC?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-web-roles

I want to combine the features and function of the Azure Web Role and Worker Role into one.  My driving reason for this is because I only need one of each, but the SLA is forcing me to get two instances of each role.

Since 4 * $0.12 / hour is more than what I want to spend out of pocket, I want to combine purposes into two highly available roles.

What factors do I need to take into account, and how would I decide between using a [Web Role with Worker Threads](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazure/thread/282e76cc-8110-4407-aa0b-0aaa31452e99) versus a Worker Role with [HWC](http://blogs.iis.net/ksingla/archive/2007/12/20/ins-amp-outs-of-hostable-web-core.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my reply on that thread... I'd use a web role and just put code in WebRole.cs like you would in WorkerRole.cs.

Comment: When would I need to use HWC then?

Comment: If you need to customize applicationHost.config or put your web content in a writable location... (that's what I do with it, anyway).